# How to fix Orm Shieldbreaker's build?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design, npc, skald, cavalier

Spoilers for Giantslayer book 5: if you suspect you're one of my players, don't read further!

### Preamble ramble

Anvil of Fire, the fifth installment of the Giantslayer original Adventure Path for Pathfinder 1e, is well known for having repetitive encounters that just amount to more enemies of the same kind in slightly different environments.

User Artofregicide on the Paizo forums saw that and decided to make their own series of encounters instead, which they published on the forums under the name of Ashpeak Revision. I'm using the latest intsallment of their encounters, v3, with the consent of my party.

Artofregicide themselves admit that the revision is just a collection of cool ideas and sometimes partial builds that need editing that will probably never come, but I like some of the ideas such as using more varied enemy Types, **changing encounters to better use the terrain in order to show that fire giants are good at tactical warfare** and having a miniboss/captain for each of the fire giant clans.

***Orm Shieldbreaker*** is one such captain.

### The room

This is a slightly modified version of room C8 from Anvil of Fire.

This long cave is divided into four enormous 10-ft. high steps of various lenght (from lowest to highest: over 100 ft., 70 ft., 55 ft. and irrelevant length) that PCs need to climb to reach the highest step where enemies with long range weapons are.

The climb can be done traditionally or using a straight central path that has 20-ft. long flights of stairs connecting the big steps, protected by gates.

On the top step there are:

- Orm, mainly being a buffer skald/cavalier
- his Iron Rhinoceros mount
- 2 variant evil legion archons with 3/day fireball and irosnkin, armed with composite longbows
- 1 variant valkyrie with 3/day delayed fireball, also armed with a composite longbow
- 2 fire giants with heavy crossbows
- 2 animated ballistae

Several other enemies will also start at the top but move to melee as the PCs approach the final raise:

- 2 young fire giants
- 2 young frost giants
- 3 wounded fire giants
- 2 fire giants
- 2 fire giant skald 5
- 1 frost giant magus 3

Due to the party being pretty strong and numerous and me having mistakingly told them to level up a few rooms too soon I will apply the Advanced template to everyone, twice.

I still expect most of those enemies not being a real threat to the PCs, being able to only ping them for some damage ...unless properly buffed by Orm.

### Party tactics (level 14)

The enemies vaguely know what the party can do. Orm was given a potion of freedom of movement.

The party can be roughly divided into hitters, buffers, controllers and lesser threats.

Hitter #1: feral hunter polymorphed into a huge fiendish prehistoric rhino. Buffs the party and himself, then uses a 24d6+30 damage attack and a swift 12d6+30 damage attack. High AC, DR 10.
Hitter #2: large humanoid ancestor eidolon with a glaive. Also uses hurtful for that sweet swift attack. Even higher AC, immune to fire, sacrificable.
Hitter #3: mounted barbarian that shares rage powers with his huge giganotosaurus mount (x5 damage from using a lance and having automatic criticals on a charge, plus the dinosaur's attacks). Attacks from the ceiling, to avoid bumping into other combatants, and the ceiling here is sloped but flat so he's effectively flying.
Hitter #4: ranged ranger (favored enemy: giants), usual fixed turret archer tactics.
Hitter #5: underequipped rogue NPC. Never manages to get behind enemies before they die to the rest of the party.
Hitter #6: summoned always invisible void elementals from the void kineticist. One of them carries a training weapon for making coup-de-grace on pinned enemies as a standard action.

Buffers: ranger provides live bubble, summoner provides haste then just flies around invisible, hunter provides favored enemy giants to everyone. Fire resistance 30 is sometimes given to the party by either the hunter or the summoner.

Controller: void kineticist can use telekinetic maneuvers to grapple from afar. Very high CMB.

Healers: boots of the earth for everyone but the quadrupeds. Kineticist can healing.

### Custom skald archetype

All skalds in this room use this archetype. I know, it gives high level magus features to skalds at level 1. It's thematic to the fire giant deity. It's NPCs only.

**Proficiencies:**
A Steel Singer Skald is proficient in simple weapons, martial weapons, light, medium, and heavy armor as well as shields except for tower shields. They may cast skald spells in any armor without incurring a spell failure chance.

**Harbinger of Steel:**
At first level, a steel singer gains armor focus as a bonus feat. Additionally, at 5th level they gain the armor training ability from the fighter class, and may move at full speed in medium armor. At 9th level they may move at full speed in heavy armor. They do not gain advanced armor training from this class.
This replaces scribe scroll and spell keening gained at 5th. Spell keening is gained at 11th and 17th, for a total of 2 uses per day.

**Mettle:**
A steel singer gains a +4 insight on saving throws vs. fear.
This replaces well-versed.

**Raging Song:**
In addition to the normal benefits of raging song, creatures wearing medium or heavy armor treat their armor bonus as one higher and their ACP as one lower for the duration of the raging song. However, the bonus to will saves don't start until 4th.
This alters raging song.

**Song of Unbroken Blades:**
Under the effects of this performance, all equipment that a creature carries gains a bonus to it's hardness equal to the skald's level, and all creatures gain a bonus equal to half the skald's level on CMD vs. sunder attempts.
This replaces song of strength

### Steel blessed template

All fire giants in this room have this homebrew template

- see in darkness
- heatsense 60ft (blindsense, only applies to creatures with body heat)
- immunity to profane damage from hellfire and flamestrike
- proficiency in all martial weapons at least partially made of metal
- increase the fire damage from heated rock to 3d6 total
- +4 profane bonus to hit and damage all rock throwing attacks
- +2 insight bonus on saving throws vs. mind effecting
- +4 profane bonus to Charisma

SLAs (CL15, concentration +19)
(3/day) Reach (close) Shackle (DC16), Fireball (DC17), Make Whole
(1/day) Wall of Fire (DC18), Fear (DC18)
(1/week) Fabricate

## Orm Shieldbreaker

Below is Orm's original build. He's missing at least his skald's rage powers ad a standard (I think the stalwart standard is the best?), and the build seems a bit incoherent anyway at a first glance. Like, is he a buffer that can stop being a buffer and use a warhammer if people get in melee with him? Is he even sharing any feat with allies like cavaliers do?

I think this build is not top notch and I would like to know how to improve it.

**The best build ideally does the following:**

- keeps his age, race, ability score spread, class choices and at least the custom archetype choice (at least one cavalier level, at least a few skald levels, the rest can be swapped for something else)
- makes him hard to deal with, as a real miniboss should
- makes him shine with the setup of the room he chose for his last stand, reinforcing the idea that fire giants know their tactics
- still recognizably produces "old, one-armed, flag-bearing, drum-pounding Orm"
- fits the aesthethic of Zursvaater and if possible of the halberd-wielding clan Brandrik
- has a use for his cavalier class levels (I'm not married to flagbearing archetypes but then something

#### The original build

Captain Orm Shieldbreaker
Old Fire Giant Skald (Steel Singer) 9/Cavalier (Standard Bearer) 2 CR14

LE Large humanoid (fire, giant)
Init +4;
FCB: skills (9)

Senses low-light vision, heat sense (blindsense 60ft.), see in darkness;
Perception +19

Defense
AC 30, touch 9, flat-footed 30 (+13 armor, +1 deflection, +8 natural, –1 size, -1 raging song)
hp 331 (24d8+2d10+208)
Fort +22, Ref +10, Will +17 (+2 vs. mindaffecting)
Defensive Abilities rock catching; Immune fire
Weaknesses one arm, vulnerability to cold

Offense
Speed 40 ft. (40 ft. in armor)
Melee +1 adamantine warhammer +32/+27/+22 (2d6+19/19-20x3) or slam +30 (1d8+12)
Ranged mwk shotput +23/+18 (2d6+22 plus 3d6 fire) or rock +22/+17 (1d8+22 plus 3d6 fire)
Space 10 ft., Reach 10 ft.
Special Attacks superheated rock, rock throwing (120 ft.)

SLAs (CL15, concentration +19)
(3/day) Reach (close) Shackle (DC16), Fireball (DC17), Make Whole
(1/day) Wall of Fire (DC18), Fear (DC18)
(1/week) Fabricate

Skald Spells (CL9, concentration +14)
lv 3) Cure Serious Wounds, Dispel Magic, Gaseous Form, Slow (4/day)
lv 2) Allegro, Bladed Dash, Cure Moderate Wounds, Heroism (5/day)
lv 1) Alarm, Cure Light Wounds, Clarion Call, Grease, Moment of Greatness, Silent Image, Unseen Servant (7/day)
lv 0) Detect Magic, Message, Mending, Prestidigitation, Read Magic, Spark

Statistics
Str 34, Dex 10, Con 24, Int 12, Wis 16, Cha 20
Base Atk +19; CMB +23; CMD 33

Feats Cleave, Great Cleave,Improved Sunder, Great Sunder, Iron Will, Power Attack, Weapon Focus (warhammer), Improved Critical (warhammer), Armor Focus, Vital Strike, Toughness, Giant Wallop, Giant Crush, Will of Giants, Improved Initiative

Skills bluff +33, craft (blacksmith) +16, handle animal +33, intimidate +37, knowledge (all) +5, perception +19, perform (sing) +33, perform (percussion) +35, ride +10, sense motive +31, spellcraft +14

ACP -3

SQ one arm

Gear +1 adamantine warhammer, light hammer (3), +2 fullplate, belt of STR, DEX +2, cloak resist +2, boulder bag, (3) mwk shotputs (better boulders), ring of protection +1, wand of CLW (14 charges), mwk mammoth hide drum

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it more closely resembles a forum post than a stack exchange style question.  Awnseres will be opinion baised.

Comment: @PlayPatrice I have seen well received questions, usually asking for how to build a PC, where the answer was a full-fledged build and I was trying to get the same effect, but for an NPC. Would you close those ones too, or do you recognize some difference that could help me reshape my qyuestion intos something better for the stack? (Or should we be having this conversation in meta?)

Comment: This isn't a question about how to build X.  Its a speculative question regarding a nebulus target that is going to rely heavily on opinion and prefrences rather than a statistical benchmark.  It's also a heavily compound question.   This is different than, "How do I build a fighter with X AC and max damage".   Putting it into the realm of a forum discussion due to the extreme number of variables and opinion biased prefrences.   How do I build a stealth scout?  Is different question than "How do I make the best gnome ever".

Comment: Would if be less speculative if I turned it into damage output optimization for the allies in the room within the constraints of "heavy armor, music magic, carrying a flag, one arm, old fire giant"?
Keep in mind that by now I have two questions and, unless I missed something, I can clearly see which one buffs their party's ranged attacks the most. (Sadly, it is mine, and I'm hoping something better exists.)
Or I might rework this into "Is this the better I can do?" now that I have a build of my own... maybe as a new uestion since this one already has answers.

Answer (score 3):

### Section 1: Ally Management

The entire elite 'honour guard' is equipped for ranged combat, constructs, or both. This means they receive no offensive benefit from Inspired Rage (constructs can't gain morale bonuses, and the Strength increase is wasted unless those longbows have the Adaptive property). It might work when the front line collapses, but there's a definite argument to leaving the initial buffs for the front  line to the two level 5 Skalds with them and giving Orm something that can help with the ranged support.

An aside on those level 5 Skalds: The Linnorm Death Curse powers are really funny with a large number of grunts expected to go down. The Crag version (which applies Vulnerability to Fire damage) can be taken at level 4, though skalds only get new Rage Powers at levels 3 and 6 and the rules-as-written on being able to use Extra Rage Power with Inspired rage is a clunky mess.

### Section 2: A Commander's Prestige

At this point, I have two pressing issues to resolve: have an alternate set of buffs that can help the honour guard, and find a use for the cavalier dip. The [Battle Herald prestige class from the APG](https://aonprd.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Battle%20Herald) appears to resolve both: it provides its own buff options (with a more universal Competence Bonus), and requires the Cavalier's Challenge ability to enter (it also continues to scale abilities like Tactician and Banner). It was written before the Skald, and so normally requires the Bard's Inspire Courage, but we're already in custom archetype territory so I'm just going to replace every mention of that with Inspired Rage and keep going.

Battle Herald can be potentially entered after Skald 1/ Cavalier 1 since the racial HD can be used for the skill rank and BAB requirements. I've decided to use 4 Skald levels for a few reasons: it matches the levels required for a 0HD race to enter Battle Herald, it unambiguously follows "at least a few Skald levels", and Uncanny Dodge might get some use since the opponents like using invisibility. This results in a level layout of Skald (steel singer)4/Cavalier (standard bearer) 1/ Battle Herald (skald version) 6.

### Section 3: Support Structure

With the levels decided, it's now time to focus on the selectable class features. Many of these also shape the kinds of buffs Olm can offer.

1. Rage Power (Skald 3): As mentioned in Section 1, I'm expecting that Inspired Rage isn't going to be the main buff used during the first phases of the battle. It's also only resolving at level 4 due to all the racial HD and multiclassing. As a result, I like the idea of going with a power that grants a natural attack because it can make use of the good base stats of giants/outsiders compared to something that scales with class level. Animal Fury is logistically easiest since both Olm and the others on the top level are likely to have their hand(s) full.
2. Banner (Standard Bearer 1): I agree with the assessment that Stalwart Banner is likely the best option. The others don't have much for a backline situation. Note that it gets a +3 to CMD since Battle Herald levels count for Banner progression.
3. Order (Cavalier 1): With only one level, this only affects the Challenge, which isn't part of the main event. I go with Order of the Hammer (Might Makes Right) because free sunders get some use out of the hammer being adamantine.
4. Teamwork feats (Cavalier 1, Battle Herald 6): Volley fire is the main pure ranged feat, so I go with it. Point-Blank Shot will need to be swapped into the regular feats. For the second, I pick Intercept Charge to help maintain a defensive formation though I don't expect it to get used.
5. 3 Inspiring Commands (Battle Herald 1/3/5): While I'm not expecting to use the bonus to charge distance, the bonus to attack/damage from Sound the Charge can't be passed up since Olm won't have the standard Inspire Courage to fall back on. After that, Stand Firm seems like the most relevant defensive option and Teamwork could help in some situations.

### Section 4: Final build(changes in bold, explanations in italics)

Captain Orm Shieldbreaker

Old Fire Giant Skald (Steel Singer) **4**/Cavalier (Standard Bearer) **1/Battle Herald (skald)6** CR14

---

LE Large humanoid (fire, giant)

Init +4;

FCB: skills (**4**)*fewer levels in skald*

Senses low-light vision, heat sense (blindsense 60ft.), see in darkness;

Perception **+23**

---

Defense

**AC 31, touch 10, flat-footed 31** (+13 armor, +1 deflection, +8 natural, –1 size)

**hp 284 (19d8+7d10+156)**

**Fort +22, Ref +10, Will +15** (+2 vs. mindaffecting) *class readjustment, no longer assumes inspired rage*

Defensive Abilities rock catching; Immune fire, **Uncanny Dodge**

Weaknesses one arm, vulnerability to cold

---

Offense

Speed 40 ft. (**30** ft. in armor)*no longer reaches high enough level in steelsinger*

Melee +1 adamantine warhammer **+33/+28/+23 (2d6+20/19-20x3+1d6 fire)** or slam **+31 (1d8+13)**

Ranged mwk shotput **+26/+21 (2d6+23 plus 3d6 fire)** or rock **+25/+20 (1d8+23 plus 3d6 fire)**

*No longer assumes inspired rage, now assumes Sound The Charge inspiring command*

Space 10 ft., Reach 10 ft.

Special Attacks superheated rock, rock throwing (120 ft.), **Raging Song (14 rounds, +2 Str/Con, +2 Will, -1 AC, bite attack), Inspiring Command +3 (19 rounds, swift action), Tactician 1/day, Challenge 1/day**

SLAs (CL15, concentration +19)

(3/day) Reach (close) Shackle (DC16), Fireball (DC17), Make Whole

(1/day) Wall of Fire (DC18), Fear (DC18)

(1/week) Fabricate

Skald Spells (CL**4**, concentration +**9**)

**lv 2) Allegro, Heroism (2/day)**

**lv 1) Cure Light Wounds, Clarion Call, Grease, Silent Image (5/day)**

lv 0) Detect Magic, Message, Mending, Prestidigitation, Read Magic, Spark

*reduced from fewer skald levels*

---

Statistics

**Str 30**, Dex 10, **Con 20**, Int 12, Wis 16, Cha 20

Base Atk +19; **CMB +21; CMD 34**  *no longer assumes inspired rage, includes CMD bonus from banner*

Feats

Cleave, Great Cleave,Improved Sunder, Great Sunder, Iron Will, Power Attack, Weapon Focus (warhammer), Improved Critical (warhammer), Armor Focus, **Point-Blank Shot**, Toughness, **Flame Warrior, Cunning,** Will of Giants, Improved Initiative, **Volley Fire, Intercept Charge**
*Point-Blank shot is required for volley fire, Cunning more than makes up for the skill point losses for the prestige class and its requirements. Without Vital Strike, lacks the ability to use the Giant-specific feats so I added Flame Warrior as a flavour replacement.*

Skills

bluff +33, craft (blacksmith) +16, handle animal +33, intimidate +37, knowledge (all) **+3**, perception **+23**, perform (**Oratory**) +33, perform (percussion) +35, ride +10, sense motive +31, spellcraft +14, **Profession(Soldier) +8, Diplomacy +13**
*Knowledge reduced from fewer Skald levels, Oratory, Soldier, and Diplomacy required to enter Battle Herald, spare ranks from Cunning into Perception*

ACP **-5**

SQ one arm, **Stalwart Standard, Voice of Authourity, Easy March**

---

Gear

+1 adamantine warhammer, light hammer (3), +2 fullplate, belt of STR, DEX +2, cloak resist +2, boulder bag, (3) mwk shotputs (better boulders), ring of protection +1, wand of CLW (14 charges), mwk mammoth hide drum

Comment: It's not a "clunky mess", it just completely destroys my idea. See the [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gw#v5748eaic9ugx)

Answer (score 0):

### Room analysis

NPC tactics in this room involve a large firing squad that attacks at a distance, forcing the PCs to close the distance (the steps and the gates being mostly there to slow them down) or to turn the tables with more ranged damage.

Given the composition of the PC party, the kineticist alone could just keep summoning elementals and send them in, singlehandedly defeating the opposition with an attrition war, but let's suppose there's some urgency (or a genlemen agreement) and the party attacks with full force, otherwise whatever build Orm uses changes absolutely nothing.

Given the composition of the rest of the party, the enemies should probably target the archer and the kineticist first because of their ranged options, while slowing the melee's ascent as much as they can.

Dealing a lot of damage at range is therefore essential and rock throwing's range is too short so it befalls to the animated ballistae, archons and valkyrie.

Given how all of those are very low CR with respect to the party, the hardest part for them will be to hit, therefore Orm should focus more on boosting attack rolls than damage.

### Cavalier benefits analysis

The Standard Bearer archetype does almost nothing since Orm already has enough slots to cast heroism on anyone in the room who is not immune to morale effects, and the only worthy standard is the Stalwart Standard, which is a morale effect.

Sadly, the other option (the flagbearer feat) is also a morale feat.

Therefore, the flag will be cosmetical only anyway. Despite all good intentions at actually making it relevant, it just isn't and the Cavalier levels might even be a dead weight.

Challenge does almost nothing (a measly +2 damage against a single enemy that, at these levels, would not balance the -2 AC to attacks from the target's allies unless they're all dead already)

Luckily, second level in cavalier gives them access to an order, and the Order of the Lion (which is thematic as the Brandik clan is the clan to which the king belongs) gives a +1 competence bonus to hit to all allies for 4 rounds. Not exceptional, but every little bit counts.

Even better, cavalier 2 gets one more round of Tactician and one more round of the Volley Fire teamwork feat is pretty great for this room.

### Skald levels analysis

While one more level in skald would gain Orm access to level 4 spells, I have not found any that really helps except maybe Freedom of Movement.

Since I was already going to have Orm drink a potion of it, 9 levels seems the optimal choice because it gets a third rage level and only rage levels coming from class levels can be passed with Inspired Rage.

There are a few rage powers that affect ranged attacks:

- scent helps with invisible creatures and allows using pheromone arrows
- reckless abandon provides +3 to hit and -3 to AC at level 8
- savage hurl gets another +3 to thrown weapons, which boulders should qualify as
- surprise accuracy is another +3, but it's a morale effect.

Here the choice is between scent, which helps the three archers with a +2 to hit and to damage, or surprise accuracy, which gives a +1 to hit to all archers and giants once per turn.
I will go with Surprise Accuracy because archons are pretty bad at archery and should focus on spellcasting instead, so the pheromone arrows would only really benefit the valkyrie.

I thought of using Wall of Split Illumination to shroud defenders in darkness, so the fire giants at least can use their archetype's see in darkness for some asimmatrical warfare.

## Changes to the build

Feats were too many (despite standard fire giants having a bonus feat that is not marked as such in their statblocks) so I had to remove some.

Feats Cleave, Great Cleave, Improved Sunder, Iron Will, Power Attack, Weapon Focus (warhammer), Improved Critical (warhammer), Vital Strike, Toughness, Giant Wallop, Giant Crush, Will of Giants, Point Blank Shot, Volley Fire (bonus from tactician)

Wall of Split Illumination instead of the very un-cavalier-ish Gaseous Form.

Order of the Lion.

Banner: any. They all do nothing.

Rage powers: Reckless Abandon, Savage Hurl, Surprise Accuracy.